# Pytest --doctest-modules executes scripts

Tags: python, testing, pytest

I have this MRE:

```
.
└── tests
    └── notest.py
```

The `notest.py` just do a `sys.exit(1)`:

When I run `pytest --doctest-modules` I get this error:

```
ERROR collecting tests/notest.py
tests/notest.py:4: in <module>
    sys.exit(1)
E   SystemExit: 1
```

So the `--doctest-modules` would try to execute my script which is not a test. Is that normal behaviour and how to prevent that?

Comment: Unfortunately it is, which can make it difficult to enable doctest on a big code base. Another caveat: pytest accepts file level `__test__ = False` (from nosetests) but doctest chokes on it: `AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'items'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is that normal behaviour?

Yes. Passing `--doctest-modules` will activate a special doctest collector that is not restricted to globs specified by [`python_files`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#confval-python_files) (`test_*.py` and `*_test.py` by default). Instead, it will find and collect any python module that is not `__init__.py` or `__main__.py`. Afterwards, `doctest` will import them to collect docstrings and execute doctests from every module.

> how to prevent that?

If you have doctests in `notest` you want to run, you have to prevent code execution on `notest` module import. Place the code that causes premature exit into `if __name__ == '__main__'` block:

```
# notest.py
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(1)
```

Now the regular import (e.g. `python -c 'import tests.notest'`) will exit with 0 as the main block is not executed, while running the module (e.g. `python tests/notest.py` or `python -m tests.notest`) will still exit with 1.

---

If you have no tests in the `notest` module or you can't edit its code, you can instruct `pytest` to ignore the module completely:

```
$ pytest --doctest-modules --ignore=tests/notest.py
```

or persist the option in `pyproject.toml` or `pytest.ini` to avoid entering the option every time. Example with `pyproject.toml`:

```
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
addopts = "--ignore=tests/notest.py"
```

Alternatively, this can also be done in a `conftest` module. Example:

```
# tests/conftest.py
collect_ignore = ["notest.py"]
```

Beware that `collect_ignore` receives files relative to the current `conftest` module. Therefore, if you use a `conftest` in the project root directory (on the same level as `tests` directory), you would have to specify the correct relative path:

```
# conftest.py
collect_ignore = ["tests/notest.py"]
```